# solving this radical equation; finding the value of q?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

So, here's my question:$\sqrt{\frac{q^{2}}2 + 11} = q - 1$

I solved it up to this point: $ q^{2} - 4q - 20 = 0$

The answer is $q = 2 + 2\sqrt{6}$

I'm missing a step... what is it? How should I get this final answer?

Comment: Why not using the quadratic formula to solve your quadratic equation. There will be 2 solutions. One of them happens to work...

Comment: @imranfat my math teacher did not teach us that method; basically he skipped a chapter explaining it and wants us to solve this equation in a different way

Comment: You can either complete the square or apply the Quadratic Formula to solve the equation $q^2 - 4q - 20 = 0$.  You then have to substitute the values you obtain into the original equation to see if they work.

Answer (score 1):

$$q^2-4q-20=0$$
$$q^2-4q=20$$
$$(q-2)^2=20+4$$
$$(q-2)^2=24$$
$$q-2=\pm\sqrt{24}$$
$$q=2\pm\sqrt{24}$$
One of them works, the other one is extraneous

Comment: why and how did you add 4 to both sides and wrote the left hand side as a square (i know it's to complete the square but i wanna understand it more)

Comment: Because when you expand $(q-2)^2$ you get $q^2-4q+4$, so thinking "in reverse", I had to add 4 to the right hand side in order to "replace" $q^2-4q$ by $(q-2)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Because you need to write $q\geq1$ before.

Now, we need to solve
$$\frac{q^2}{2}+11=(q-1)^2$$ or
$$q^2-4q-20=0,$$ which gives
$$q=2+\sqrt{24}$$ or $q=2-\sqrt{24}$, which is impossible.